# Mongo service killed when connect from MongoCompass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I installed mongo locally using homebrew and added a replicaset and everything seems working fine when I use `mongosh`. then I installed MongoCompass and whenever I try to connect  the DB the service killed I have to restart the mongo service from homebrew.
and here is my mongod.conf file

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  ipv6: true
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
  oplogSizeMB: 100
```

can you please advise me?

**Edit:** I tried to remove the replication from mongod.conf and I was able to connect from MongoCompass normally, yet I need the replication as my app working with sessions

Comment: Did you initiate the replica set? Did you check the logfile `/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`?

Comment: yes, I can see that i'm using the `rs0` when I connect via `mongosh`, @WernfriedDomscheit